# SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed (postfix + cyrus + saslauthd)

Tags: postfix, saslauthd, centos7

We're having difficulties authenticating over smtp, running postfix + cyrus on centos 7.

When I try to telnet to port 25 (or 587) locally and auth plain, I get the following errors in the mail log:

> Sep 25 10:25:00 blabla postfix/smtpd[3858]: warning: SASL authentication problem: unable to open Berkeley db /etc/sasldb2: Permission denied
>
> Sep 25 10:25:00 blabla postfix/smtpd[31106]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed
>
> Sep 25 10:25:00 blabla postfix/smtpd[31106]: warning: unknown[::1]: SASL plain authentication failed: authentication failure

Not sure what sasldb2 has to do with anything and if that warning has any real bearing on the problem.
`testsaslauthd` with the same credentials returns OK.

Postfix is **not** running in `chroot` mode:

```
smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
smtps      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
submission inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
                   -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
```

I'm using `/etc/shadow` for authentication, so `ps aux | grep sasl` says:

```
/usr/sbin/saslauthd -m /var/run/saslauthd -a shadow
```

Socket dir is `/var/run/saslauthd` so in `main.cf`, I have:

```
smtpd_sasl_path = /var/run/saslauthd/
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
tls_random_source               = dev:/dev/urandom
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks = <someip>
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    check_policy_service unix:/var/spool/postfix/postgrey/socket
```

Finally, `/etc/sasl2/smtpd.conf` has:

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN
saslauthd_path: /var/run/saslauthd/
allow_plaintext: true
```

Any pointers? I am stumped...

Most of the docs I find online seem to point to chrooted postfix configs or more complicated auth methods.

Comment: Could you add IP address of smtp client to [debug_peer_list](http://postfix.org/postconf.5.html#debug_peer_list) directive in main.cf? It will turn on debug log for your IP where you tested smtp auth.

Comment: Done but it's not telling me anything else.
One update: I'm also getting warning: SASL authentication problem: unable to open Berkeley db /etc/sasldb2: Permission denied
(updated original description)

Comment: If the **verbose log** doesn't tell you anything, then add to above question. Perhaps, some folks here can get additional info from the verbose log.

Answer (score 2):

The error message

> unable to open Berkeley db /etc/sasldb2: Permission denied

was generic message that postfix can't open that directory because permission issue. Use chmod and/or chown to grant access on `/etc/sasldb2` to postfix

```
chown postfix:postfix /etc/sasldb2
chmod 660 /etc/sasldb2
```

or

```
chmod 644 /etc/sasldb2
```

For security reason, I would suggest the first option.

Reference: [blog.penumbra.be](http://blog.penumbra.be/2010/04/authenticated-smtp-postfix/) | [www.murat.ws](http://www.murat.ws/warning-sasl-authentication-problem-unable-to-open-berkeley-db-etcsasldb2-permission-denied/) | [this thread](http://lists.andrew.cmu.edu/pipermail/info-cyrus/2007-January/024906.html)

Comment: Eventually I did that and got rid of that message. Unfortunately, this didn't get rid of the general auth problem. (which kinda makes sense since I'm not using sasldb2 to authenticate)